# Calling a function in AngularJS service from the same service?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS service defined in the following way

```
angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {
  this.publicFunction(param) {
    ...
  };

  this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
    // how to call publicFunction(param)?
    ...
  };
});
```

and I would like to call the first function both from outside the service (which works fine by `myService.publicFunction(xxx)`) and from another function in the same service, i.e. `anotherPublicFunction`. <del>Neither one of `this.publicFunction(param)` or `myService.publicFunction(param)` won't work from within the second function, and I can understand that.</del>

---

**EDIT:**
*Actually the whole problem was caused by something you can't reproduce with my example alone. I passed the second function as a callback parameter to another function in a separate controller, and when it is called, the reference to `this` doesn't work.*

*E.g.*

```
anotherService.someCall('a', 123, myService.anotherPublicFunction);
```

*fails inside `anotherPublicFunction` because `this` can't be resolved.*

*I've written a Plunker to show the problem:*
http://plnkr.co/edit/rrRs9xnZTNInDVdapiqF?p=info

*(I'll still leave the question here in case it will help someone else.)*

---

I know I could get around the problem by using a reference to the service or the first function like this

```
var ms = this;
this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
  ms.publicFunction(param);
  ...
};
```

or this

```
var pf = this.publicFunction;
this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
  pf(param);
  ...
};
```

but both seem like dirty hacks.

**Is there a good way to call the first function from the second one in this case? Or am I doing something totally wrong in the first place to have a service like this?**

I found these questions with good answers:

- [Angularjs share functions inside service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753825/angularjs-share-functions-inside-service)
- [AngularJs call an internal service function from self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853797/angularjs-call-an-internal-service-function-from-self)

but they differ from my problem since one of them has a separate, internal function that was to be called, and the other one was using a factory instead of a service.

**EDIT:**

After posting this I immediately realized I could also do this:

```
var actualWork = function(param) {
  ...
}

this.publicFunction(param) {
  actualWork(param);
};

this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
  actualWork(param);
  ...
};
```

which doesn't seem quite as bad as the other options so far... Are there better approaches?

Comment: Why do you call `var ms = this;` (which is written more often as `var self = this;`) "a dirty hack"?

Comment: It's just a matter of personal taste and stems from my background (especially in Java). Using a new "pointer" to another variable `this` in the same scope just feels weird... But `this` is a special reference and JavaScript has this kind of lexical closure, so it's one of those things I should probably just accept and embrace when writing JS code. When in Rome etc.

Answer (score 40):

I think the best way is to go like this:

```
var myFunctions = 
{

    myFunc1: function(param) {

    },

    myFunc2: function(param) {
       return foo + myFunctions.myFunc1(param)// do some stuff with the first function        
    }

}
return myFunctions;
```

because I think if you use *this*, it may get conflict with the scope where you use the service.

Comment: OP's final edit is what works. Just declare var foo = function(){...} and call foo() in bar like bar = function(){...foo()...}

Comment: it's a service, you use "this"

Answer (score 33):

I ran into this problem within my own angular coding and opted to use this form of the solution:

```
angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {
  var myService = this;
  myService.publicFunction(param) {
    ...
  };

  myService.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
    myService.publicFunction(param);
    ...
  };
});
```

I preferred this approach because in my code I use publicFunction and inside of anotherPublicFunction I loop over several params that need to call publicFunction as part of the process.

Comment: very simple. Excellent!

Answer (score 8):

Sounds good but what do you do when `this` is no longer `=` the service ?

This is the case in the following example:

```
return {

        myFunc1: function(param) {

        },

        myFunc2: function(param) {

            scope.$watchCollection(param,function(v) {

              return foo + this.myFunc1(param)// do some stuff with the first function 

            }       
        }

}
```

Because of `function(v) {` you are now in another function within the function and this is no longer the service but the window.

Answer (score 4):

You can just return an object from within your service like

```
return {

    myFunc1: function(param) {

    },

    myFunc2: function(param) {
       return foo + this.myFunc1(param)// do some stuff with the first function        
    }

}
```

So you access it from the outside with `service.myFunc1` and from inside its internal functions with this.

Comment: Thank you for this. As I tried this out in my code, and then in a Plunker, I realized the original problem was only a side effect of something else. It seems my "problematic" code actually works in the way I've presented it in my question.

Answer (score 4):

You can set 'this' as variable

```
angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {
  var that = this;
  this.publicFunction(param) {
    ...
  };

  this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
    that.publicFunction(param);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, just create two more pointers/function variables for your service functions with local variables in service and use those to call the service functions from within same service :

*

```
angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {
  **var ref1, ref2;**
  this.publicFunction = **ref1** = function(param) {
    ...
  };
  this.anotherPublicFunction = **ref2** = function(param) {
    // how to call publicFunction(param)?
    **ref1(argument);**
    ...
  };
});
```

- 

Answer (score 0):

this is how I implemented:

```
.service('testSvc', function () {
return {
    f1: function (v1) {
        alert('f1 > v1=' + v1);
    },
    f2: function (v2) {
        alert('f2 > v2=' + v2);
        this.f1('az'); //use 'this'
    }
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me:-

```
 angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {

    var self= {
        this.publicFunction(param) {
 ...
 };

 this.anotherPublicFunction(param) {
 // You can call the publicfunction like below
 self.publicFunction(param);
 ...
 };
 return self;

 }
 ]);`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myService').service('myService', function() {
    return {
      myFunc2: function(param) {
        return foo + myFunc1(param);
      }
    };
    function myFunc1(param){
        ...
    };
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Best and easiest way to call is:

```
myapp.service("SomeService", function ($http) {

    this.func1 = function (params) {
        // Some thing the service returns
        return something;
    }

    this.func2 = function (params) {
        // Some thing the service returns
        var resp = this.func1(params);
        return something;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the factory declaration instead of service, you can:-

```
angular.module('myService').factory('myService', function() {
  var myService = {};
  myService.publicFunction = function(param) {
    ...
  };

  myService.anotherPublicFunction = function(param) {
    // call publicFunction(param) like so
    myService.publicFunction(param);
  };

  return myService;
});
```