# Calling a function in AngularJS service from the same service but within $watchcollection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

this is a follow up question to this topic:
[Calling a function in AngularJS service from the same service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842669/calling-a-function-in-angularjs-service-from-the-same-service/20052641#20052641)

I realized too late I should open a new question instead asking it there (sorry for that)

I want to do the following:  calling a function within a service function with the additional difficulty the call is within $watchCollection. It looks something like this:

return {

```
myFunc1: function(param) {

},

myFunc2: function(scope,param) {

    scope.$watchCollection(param,function(v) {

      return foo + this.myFunc1(param)// do some stuff with the first function 

    }       
}
```

}
Because of function(v) { you are now in another function within the function and `this` is no longer the service but the `window`.

how can I get access to this myFunc1 within the myFunc2 $watchCollection parameter function?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can save the `this` in another variable (usually called `self` or `that`) and use it to access `myFunc1`.

```js
myFunc1: function(param) {

},

myFunc2: function(scope,param) {

    var self = this;
    scope.$watchCollection(param,function(v) {

      return foo + self.myFunc1(param)// do some stuff with the first function 

    }       
}
```