# AngularJS - Call function in service from the same service

Tags: angularjs, vlc, angularjs-service

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" id="PlayOrPause" style="width:60px" value="Play" onClick='doPlayOrPause();'>
```

**Ctrl**

```
$scope.doPlayOrPause = function(){
 cameraModuleService.doPlayOrPause();
}
```

**Service**

```
cameraModuleService.service('cameraModuleService', function ($http, $timeout, ENV, $log, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $compile) {  

    this.getVLC = function(){
    if( window.document[name] ){
        return window.document[name];
    }
    if( navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1 ){
        if( document.embeds && document.embeds[name] )
            return document.embeds[name];
    }else{
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
    }

    this.doPlayOrPause = function(){
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
    if( vlc )
    {
        if( vlc.playlist.isPlaying )
            vlc.playlist.togglePause();
        else
            vlc.playlist.play();
    }
    }
);
```

Here I am calling service `getVLC`, but it says getVLC is not defined. How do I call one service from the same service ?

P.S. Both functions are in the same service

Comment: These two functions are in the same file ?

Comment: Please, provide the whole service code

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842669/calling-a-function-in-angularjs-service-from-the-same-service

Comment: Updated my question. Yes both the functions are in same service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these two functions are in the same file, you have to save the reference on `this` like this:

```
var self = this;
this.doPlayOrPause = function(){
    var vlc = self.getVLC("vlc");
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
cameraModuleService.service('cameraModuleService', function ($http, $timeout, ENV, $log, $rootScope, $cookieStore, $compile, $window) {

  this.getVLC = function () {
    if ($window.document[name]) {
      return $window.document[name];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet") == -1) {
      if (document.embeds && document.embeds[name])
        return document.embeds[name];
    } else {
      return document.getElementById(name);
    }
  }

  var self = this;
  this.doPlayOrPause = function () {
    var vlc = self.getVLC("vlc");
    if (vlc) {
      if (vlc.playlist.isPlaying)
        vlc.playlist.togglePause();
      else
        vlc.playlist.play();
    }
  }
  );
```

Comment: and why I can not call using `this.getVLC` instead define `var self` ? Also using its not returning anything.

Comment: Because `this` is referenced to the _function scope_ (when you called it in the function) and `getVLC` is not defined in the _function scope_, but in your service scope  `cameraModuleService`

Comment: What  changes should I make in order to make it work ?

Comment: i did the same changes in my service and it still says `undefined`. Will it get `window.document` in service.js ?

Comment: I think you have to include `$window` in your dependencies, and change `window` by `$window` (c.f update)