# Calling a variable in an Angular factory from the same factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple factory returning an array and a function:

```
function stockCommons() {
        return {
            unitTypes: [
                {
                    code: 'UN',
                    unitTypeIndex: 0
                },
                {
                    code: 'PK',
                    unitTypeIndex: 2
                },
            ],

            unitTypeChanged: function (changedToUnitType) {
                return var activeUnitType = stockCommons.unitTypes.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.code == changedToUnitType;
                })[0];
        }
    }
```

In the function I'm trying to make a reference to the array at `stockCommons.unitTypes` but it doesn't work. I've tried [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842669/calling-a-function-in-angularjs-service-from-the-same-service) but they don't work either.

How can I use the unitTypes array in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution would be to define `unitTypes` as private variable and refer it.

```
function stockCommons() {
    var unitTypes = [{
            code: 'UN',
            unitTypeIndex: 0
        }, {
            code: 'PK',
            unitTypeIndex: 2
        },
    ];

    return {
        unitTypes: unitTypes,

        unitTypeChanged: function (changedToUnitType) {
            var activeUnitType = unitTypes.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.code == changedToUnitType;
                })[0];
            return activeUnitType;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oops sorry, now I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
function stockCommons() {
        return {
            unitTypes: function() {
                this.stock = [
                {
                    code: 'UN',
                    unitTypeIndex: 0
                },
                {
                    code: 'PK',
                    unitTypeIndex: 2
                },
               ];
               return this.stock;
            },

            unitTypeChanged: function (changedToUnitType) {
                return var activeUnitType = stockCommons.unitTypes.filter(function (obj) {
                    return obj.code == changedToUnitType;
                })[0];
        }
    }
```